# Symfony Increment value in Database

Tags: database, symfony, twig, increment

I'm working on a website where people can download wallpapers.
I have a table 'Images' with a 'Download' column.
I would like to increment the value on this field for each time people click on the 'download button'
I'm usingg Symphony 6 with EasyAdmin-bundle & Twig
Can someone help me to make a query to increment this value ?
Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5xtw.png)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ImagesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ImagesRepository::class)]
class Images
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $image = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?int $downloads = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'images')]
    private ?Wallpapers $wallpaper = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'device')]
    private ?Devices $devices = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDownloads(): ?int
    {
        return $this->downloads;
    }

    public function setDownloads(?int $downloads): self
    {
        $this->downloads = $downloads;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWallpaper(): ?Wallpapers
    {
        return $this->wallpaper;
    }

    public function setWallpaper(?Wallpapers $wallpaper): self
    {
        $this->wallpaper = $wallpaper;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDevices(): ?Devices
    {
        return $this->devices;
    }

    public function setDevices(?Devices $devices): self
    {
        $this->devices = $devices;

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

```
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in wallpapers.getImages() %}
            <div class="col">
                <img src="/uploads/wps/{{ item.image }}"  class="card"/>
                <button><a href="/uploads/wps/{{ item.image }}">Download</a></button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I tried many example but as it's my first experience with Symphony is a bit complicated to understand all the concept of Query Builder

Comment: If you want to track downloads, you can't directly link to the file. You need to create a route which accepts an item as arugment. Then you can increase the views/downloads and serve the file.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new controller with route like this:

```
#[Route('/downloads/{entity}', name:'downloads')
public function downloads(
   Entity $entity,
   EntityManagerInterface $em
){
   $entity->setDownload($entity->getDownload() + 1);
   $em->persist($entity);
   $em->flush();

   return $this->file($entity->getImage(), 'name_file.ext');
}
```

in your twig file you can redirect to this func with entity id param.
Function is an example you must use your entity class and get file content to download something.